# Media Server HTTP IP Address isn't working in iOS 9 because of ATS

Tags: ios, url, ios9, app-transport-security

I used to stream radio station using HTTP server address similar to this one: http://208.53.158.48:8100.

When I tested my app in iOS 9, the app isn't streaming the radio station but in iOS 8.4 everything works great.

How can I fix this

Note:
- The other questions answered about ATS doesn't work if using IP Address as in my case (Server IP Address).I need help to exclude IP address instead of domain name?
- I only have the http address of the server
- I want a permanent solution not a temporarily one that may get dysfunctional in the future by Apple.

Comment: The fix is to allow unencrypted connections through your info.plist (or implement TLS on your streaming server, but that probably isn't going to happen, assuming that you even control the server)

Comment: Specifically, do this: http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I couldn't do that because I have no control over the server.

Comment: @EricS I can't do that because this will disable ATS entirely and this may get the App rejected.

Comment: Why do you think disabling ATS will get your app rejected?  Disabling ATS is a valid solution and Apple have never said that this is cause for rejection nor could they; there are millions of servers without https and over which app authors have no control.

Comment: @Paulw11 I know that some app passed the review process but I don't want to disable ATS entirely for all of my apps and then one day Apple decide that all apps disabling ATS will not works.I should then come back and update all of my apps.Do you think that is a permanent solution to disable ATS? I just want to see how I can add a hardcoded IP address in the info.list as an exception.Stuck here for almost a week!Thanks by the way!

Comment: I can't see how Apple can ever make the use of ATS mandatory.  If you know which IP addresses or host names need the exclusion then you can limit the exception, but if not then there is no choice other than to disable ATS generally.  If you have specific services for which ATS can be re-enabled you can also do that via an exception. For example, I have an app that uses Parse.com but also allows users to connect to an arbitrary (user defined) web service.  I disable ATS generally but enable it specifically for the Parse.com hosts

Comment: Yes I know which IP address but I don't know the domain name.In the exception domain you can't add hard-coded numerical IP addresses.